# apostrophe in PostgreSQL query comes out (32-bit) c3 a2 c2 80

Tags: postgresql

In the process of inserting rows into PostgreSQL 11.3 from a CSV file and then running queries, I ended up with (32 bits) hex "c3 a2 c2 80" in place of what was supposed to be an apostrophe (8-bit hex 27).
What happened?

Comment: Probably the input file is in a different encoding to the database.

Answer (score 1):

You messed up with the encoding. Here is a guess how you did it:

The original character was probably not an apostrophe, but either `‘` (UNICODE character 2018) or `’` (UNICODE character 2019).

The original file was probably encoded in UTF-8, where the character is encoded as Hex E2 80 98 (for U+2018) or Hex E2 80 99 (for U+2019).

Now you used `COPY` (probably `COPY FROM STDIN`, you don't give us details) with a different, single byte, encoding like `LATIN1` (ISO 8859-1). Then PostgreSQL will interpret each byte as a single character and convert it to the database encoding (`UTF8`).

The first byte (Hex E2, `â` in `LATIN1`) will become Hex C3 A2 in UTF-8, and the second byte (Hex 80, an unprintable control character in `LATIN1`) will become Hex C2 80 in UTF-8, which is exactly what you observe.

You can test my hypothesis by checking of the two next bytes are Hex C2 98 or Hex C2 99.

The solution is to specify the file encoding correctly as UTF-8 when you load the CSV file into the database. With `COPY`, you can use the `ENCODING` option to do that.